# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in E:\xampp\htdocs\

Tags: php, oop

I am getting a Fatal Error while calling a public method using Scope Resolution Operator. Here is the part of the code:

```
Class userrole {
    public function get_premium_subscritpion($userID) {
        $userID = ($userID == '') ? $this->user_info->ID : $userID;
        if (empty($userID)) return false;

        /* Check if user has subscribed */
        if ($this->get_subscription($userID) && $userID != '') {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

$role = userrole::get_premium_subscritpion(1);
```

Comment: in order to call the method such you must declare mehtod as a 
`public static function`

Comment: You can't call $this if you call the method in the static way. You must change $this-> to self::get_subscription (if get_subscription is also static). Otherwise you need to create an instance of userrole in the method or before you call get_premium_subscription.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$role = userrole::get_premium_subscritpion(1);
```

I notice that you are trying to call a non-static function in a static way

You may either change the function to static or change the way you call this function

```
public static function get_premium_subscritpion {
```

or

```
$obj = new userrole();
$role = $obj->get_premium_subscritpion(1);
```

Comment: The first change would still lead to the same error as long as `$this->get_subscription` would not also get changed into a static scope. Also assuming that this method is even inside the real `userrole` class.

Comment: i changed the public method to static but it still not worked. It still return the same error.

Comment: if you change it to static you may not use $this inside the function. Use self:: instead. But you could not do that in this case because your whole code is in a non-static context. Just try the second way I wrote. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help Eason. The second option works fine for me!!